# How to find the creation-time of a User in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

Anyone can give me advise on how to find out the detail of creation-time of a user on OpenShift?
I tried these commands but got only general information. Need to find out more detail.

```sh
$ oc describe test_user
NAME:        test_user
Created:     3 weeks ago
Labels:      <none>
Annotations: <none>
Identities:  htpasswd:test_user
```

Comment: Does `oc get user test_user -o yaml` provide a more specific timestamp?

Comment: Yes, the timestamp for user creation is described in the yaml output. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `creationTimestamp` can be found in the [User API Documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/rest_api/apis-user.openshift.io/v1.User.html)

```
$ oc get user <user> -o yaml
apiVersion: user.openshift.io/v1
fullName: "<user>"
kind: User
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-02-13T19:40:54Z"
```

Comment: Thank you. This really answer my question.